# How can I restrict users fom changing network settings and adding new connection using network manager?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I want to restrict users from changing network settings like changing IP address of the system and adding new connections,

I have removed administrator rights from the user and user is not able to change the existing connection's settings but still he can create a new connection through network-manager.

How can that be blocked?

Answer (score 2):

According to the NetworkManager website, it is build 'user-centric' and not 'system-centric'. http://www.arachnoid.com/linux/NetworkManager/

Therefore in order to achieve what you want, you should disable NetworkManager and use the init system to restrict the connection. There's a good explanation of how to do this here: http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-networking-tips-and-tricks/ Scroll down to disable NetworkManager.

Add an askubuntu question/wiki here to consolidate.